# How to specify number of decimal places in node near coords?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

Is there a way to specify that `node near coords` labels should use
1 rather than 2 decimal places?
For example, in the code below,
Singapore is printed with 8.1 (correct),
but Niger is printed with 46.12 (wrong)
when I want it instead to be 46.1 (correct).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Birth rate (births/1,000 population)},
    symbolic y coords={Niger,United States,Singapore},
    ytick=data,
    xbar,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal}]

  \addplot coordinates {
    (46.12,Niger)
    (13.42,United States)
    (8.10,Singapore)
  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=1}
```

or

```
nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=1}
```

With `fixed zerofill` a value like `4.00` will be printed as `4.0`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Birth rate (births/1,000 population)},
    symbolic y coords={Niger,United States,Singapore},
    ytick=data,
    xbar,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=1},%<- added
    enlarge x limits={upper,.15}% <-added
    ]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (46.12,Niger)
    (13.42,United States)
    (8.10,Singapore)
  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This still prints values like `6.1 * 10^-2` instead of `0.061` when using precision=3. Any idea how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Found it, in order to prevent scientific notation you can use e.g. `nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=3}`