# How to set the axes in a pgfplots barchart?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to set up a `pgfplots` barchart to look like the chart I made with Powerpoint.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[ xbar, y axis line style = { opacity = 0 }, axis x line = none, tickwidth = 0pt, enlarge y limits = 0.2, enlarge x limits = 0.02, nodes near coords, symbolic y coords = {Tool cost, Material cost,Processing cost }, legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},] 
\addplot coordinates { (1.43 ,Processing cost) (0.01,Material cost) (43.69,Tool cost)};
\addplot coordinates {  (2.43,Processing cost)  (0.01,Material cost) (8.81,Tool cost)};
\legend{CNC machining, AM}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
  \caption[Cost per part comparison with CNC machined and AM inserts]{Cost per part comparison with CNC machined and AM inserts}
\label{fig:brass_piechart}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Moreover, I am drawing a line under each figure like this

```
\decoRule{\widthof{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{CNCvsAM}}}
```

How can I adapt it to use the width of a pgfplot of 7cm?

[image]

Comment: If `\decoRule`, however that is defined, just takes a length as an argument, can't you just say `\decoRule{7cm}`?

Comment: Yes, it works but the length of the graph is not exactly 7cm isn't it?

Comment: No, perhaps not. But if you want that answered, please add the definition of `\decoRule` as well.

Comment: \newcommand{\decoRule}[1]{\rule{#1}{.4pt}}

Comment: Note that I just updated my answer a bit, I didn't think about the fact that the first coordinate changed the bounding box, so having `yshift` for both made the line a bit tilted.

Comment: Can I ask you how to change this 1*10^(-2) with 0,01?

Comment: Very close to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318672/how-to-specify-number-of-decimal-places-in-node-near-coords?rq=1, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the `\decoRule` does is draw a black line, the easiest thing is to do it as part of the `tikzpicture`, e.g. by adding

```
\draw [line width=0.4pt] ([yshift=-2pt]current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east);
```

after `\end{axis}`. Adjust the `-2pt` to your liking, or remove the `[yshift=<value>]` altogether, if you don't need it.

For the other part, you just need a couple of additions to the `axis` options, see comments in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8} 
\usepackage{eurosym} % for euro symbol
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
  xbar,
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  xmajorgrids=true, % added 
  xticklabel={\geneuro\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}, % added
  xlabel={Cost per part}, % added 
  tickwidth = 0pt,
  enlarge y limits = 0.2,
  enlarge x limits = 0.02,
  nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}, % added
  nodes near coords,
  symbolic y coords = {Tool cost, Material cost,Processing cost },
  legend style={
    at={(0.5,-0.25)}, % modified
    anchor=north,
    legend columns=-1,
    draw=none}
] 
\addplot coordinates { (1.43 ,Processing cost) (0.01,Material cost) (43.69,Tool cost)};
\addplot coordinates {  (2.43,Processing cost)  (0.01,Material cost) (8.81,Tool cost)};
\legend{CNC machining, AM}
\end{axis} 
\draw [line width=0.4pt] ([yshift=-2pt]current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east);    
\end{tikzpicture}
  \caption[Cost per part comparison with CNC machined and AM inserts]{Cost per part comparison with CNC machined and AM inserts}
\label{fig:brass_piechart}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```